# New Gas Water Heater Installation

Tags: valve, temperature, pressure

I had a brand new water heater installed back in February but by the end of May, I had water gushing out the side of my house and the plumbing company is telling me it is the temperature and pressure relief valve.

My question is that my tank was very old (thinking 19 years old) but why would they not replace the T&P relief valve at that time?  I've seen that these valves on average last about 5 years.  Any information is appreciated.

Comment: Normally a new water heater comes with a new T&P already installed. So there's either a problem causing it to operate correctly, or something does not add up in the "new water heater" installation, based on my experience of new water heaters.

Comment: take a Picture please and be quick

Comment: Have you checked your water pressure? If you have a pressure reducing device, perhaps it's failing and allowing too much pressure to be delivered to your house. To check, get a pressure gauge that connects to a hose bib and check it there. Let us know what you find out!

Comment: Is there an expansion tank?

Comment: I have to agree with George and possibly a small expansion tank is needed, every hot water er tank I have installed has had a new p&T valve so it is probably something else like a PRV, check valve or failed expansion tank.